# Jquery hover() и анимация выпадающего меню.

Tags: javascript, jquery, вёрстка, анимация

Добрый день!
Пытаюсь постигнуть азы Jquery и склепал небольшой скриптик для выпадающего меню по ховеру, но выпадает меню столько, сколько раз провел мышкой, получается такой веселый аккордеон.
Я понял что это относится к очередности анимации и ее нужно очищать, но куда прикрутить и какой метод пока не понимаю, посоветуйте что в данном случае лучше использовать?

```
  $(function(){
    $('.menu__subList').hide();
    $('.menu__item').hover(
      function(){
          $(this).find('.menu__link').addClass('menu__link_active');
          $(this).find('.menu__subList').slideDown();
      },
      function(){
          $(this).find('.menu__link').removeClass('menu__link_active');
          $(this).find('.menu__subList').slideUp('fast');
      });
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/coa685tu/

Comment: А что вам надо-то? =)

Comment: Как остановить анимацию, которая продолжается до тех пор, пока не сравняется количеству событий ховер и очистить эту очередь))    П.С. сорян, не конкретизировал проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(".parent li").hover(function() {
    $(this).find(".child").stop().slideToggle(300);
})
```

```css
ul.parent > li{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin:15px;
}
ul.child{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="parent">
    <li>ITEM 1
        <ul class="child">
            <li>item 1</li>
            <li>item 2</li>
            <li>item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>ITEM 2</li>
    <li>ITEM 2</li>
</ul>
```